# Why were these spacewalks so short?

Tags: eva, russia, mir

I got lost down the wiki hole and ended up reading a page on [Sergei Avdeyev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergei_Avdeyev) when I noticed that he has 2 very short spacewalks listed:

> 6. MIR EO-20 – 8 December 1995 – 0 hours, 37 minutes
> 7. MIR EO-26 – 15 September 1998 – 0 hours, 30 minutes

As far as I understand preparing from and then cleaning up after a spacewalk takes a lot of time and effort, so having such short spacewalks seems like a bit of a waste.

Why where these spacewalks so short? Did something happen during the walks or where they designed to be this short?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [wiki page on Mir space walks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Mir_spacewalks) has a note for each of these spacewalks. Nothing went wrong, but the reason for them were small routine tasks not taking much time. He just returned after the tasks were done.
A little more detail on the EO-20 spacewalk can be found on page 42 of [this pdf.](http://ston.jsc.nasa.gov/collections/TRS/_techrep/TP-1998-208920.pdf)
More about the EO-26 spacewalk is [here.](http://www.spacefacts.de/mir/english/mir-26.htm)